# simple unpivot on 2 rows table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

I have table that contains data of query, sample data looks like this:

```
| YEAR | JAN | FEB | ... | DEC |
|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 2013 |  90 |  40 | ... |  50 |
| 2014 |  30 |  20 | ... |  40 |
```

I'm trying to unpivot this table to have data like this:

```
| MONTH | 2013 | 2014 |
|-------|------|------|
|  JAN  |  90  |  30  |
|  FEB  |  40  |  20  |
|  ...  |  ... |  ... |
|  DEC  |  50  |  40  |
```

I've tried this:

```
select Month, 2013, 2014
from Data
unpivot
(
  marks
  for Month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)
) u
```

but all I get are months and years. Here is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd711/1)

I will always have 12 months, but I can have multiple data rows.
Can this be done without dynamic sql?

Comment: Multiple rows you mean the rows which will be transformed to columns or will be aggregated in to this tow columns?

Comment: multiple rows means that I may have data for 3 years instead of two, but for now I need only for 2 rows, 2 rows = 2 columns, like in data in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to get what you want with a single unpivot statement.  Start with this unpivot:

```
with cte(Year, Month, Orders)
as
(
  select Year, Month, Orders
  from Data d
  unpivot
  (
    orders
    for Month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr)
  ) u
)
```

I'm going to use those results in the next part, so I store it as a CTE.  This query gives you results like this:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | ORDERS |
|------|-------|--------|
| 2013 |  JAN  |  90    |
| 2013 |  FEB  |  40    |
| 2013 |  MAR  |  30    |
etc...
```

I don't know what the numbers in your table represent, but I just called them orders.  You can rename that column to whatever is appropriate.  The next step is to pivot those results so that we can get the year displayed as columns:

```
select Month, [2013], [2014]
from cte
pivot
(
  sum(orders)
  for year in ([2013], [2014])
) p
order by datepart(mm, Month+'1900')
```

If you need to add more years, it should be obvious where to do that.  Note the clever `order by` that sorts the months chronologically instead of alphabetically.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd711/18).

Comment: Thank You so much! I was trying to do that with a single statement, but as You wrote this isn't possible (maybe is, but whats the point). I like nice explanation, this helps understanding code.